# Getting railways to show up at lower zoom levels

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I need to highlight a country's railways at zoom level ~4, and I'd like to do so just using the mapbox-streets-v8 data, but not matter what I seem to do, in Mapbox Studio, in the style JSON, or in the code, I can't seem to get the road/railways layer to be visible at a zoom level under 8.

It looks like, from tinkering around in Mapbox Studio, the source isn't even loaded until zoom 8, since the features don't appear as "filtered out", they just don't appear at all. I've set the "zoom extent" down to 5 on the layer (as low as it will go), but nothing I do seems to actually get it to appear at zoom 5, let alone at a level more zoomed out:

[image: lower zoom level, railways not displayed at all, even as "filtered out"]

[image: zoom level of 8, railways are suddenly visible]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. The data doesn't exist at that zoom level in those vector tiles. You would need to prepare your own vector tiles from your own data source.